# How to attach files

Tags: discussion

How do I attach some files to a question? Or can I?

It doesn't like my grammar. If it were done when it were done it were well it were done quickly.

Comment: Looks like a meta-question, doesn’t it?

Comment: Short answer: You can't. By design.

Comment: Thanks again cfr.

Comment: *If it were done, then it were well it were done quickly.* Surely?

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/6576/21344